# Windows - Set permission on folder only without recursing subobjects (slow for large directory trees)

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-10, access-control-list

There are many times when I wish to set a permission on a folder only, but all the programs i've tried will recurse through all sub files and folders during the process. As this is slow, is there any way to avoid this?

Things i've tried:

- Windows Explorer: fails, as you can see in the gui, it will loop
  through all subobjects.
- [SetAcl.exe](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/) from Helge Klein: fails, as revealed by a nifty tool called [ProcessMonitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

  `SetACL.exe -on "PATH" -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:USER;p:read_ex;i:np;m:set" -rec no`

  For those who don't know, the "i:np" clause means the permission shall apply to "this folder only".
- icacls: fails (Process Monitor)

  `icacls "PATH" /grant USER:(NP)RX` (does the same thing as the setacl command above)

(command lines just examples)

Comment: Incidentally, you don't actually need the (NP) flag in those examples, so long as you don't say (OI) or (CI) then the permission will not be inherited. (NP) is meant to be used in *combination* with (CI) to limit the inheritance to a single level - it means that only the direct children of the object should inherit the permission, rather than the entire tree.  (It isn't often used.)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm using a powershell script to apply an audit rule to hundreds of folders, many which have thousands of files/folders so it takes a painful amount of time for me to apply. With Windows Explorer, if I add the audit then cancel the task immedietly, it's applied. Anyone have a solution or modern tool that can accomplish this without a scan of the entire structure before applying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [modern Windows API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setsecurityinfo) automatically recurses through the directory tree when a program changes the permissions on a directory, there is no option to prevent this from happening.  Nor is Windows quite smart enough to realize when a particular change has no effect on the child objects.

However, if a program uses the older [SetFileSecurity function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winbase/nf-winbase-setfilesecuritya) this does not happen.

So you might try looking for old utilities, e.g., written for Windows 2000 or earlier.

Or you can use the built-in `cacls` command line tool, it is not as convenient to use as `icacls` and is officially deprecated, but it does not affect child objects unless you pass the `/t` option.

Comment: Beautiful. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: From my experience "cacls" will set permissions with inheritance `(OI)(CI)`, despite not recursing subdirectories. That is not what we want.

Comment: This is funny. If I start changing the permission from explorer and cancel the task, the permission will get set. But if I do the same with icacls it won't. There has to be some difference between explorer and icacls.